# pass data to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an App for showing some movie infos. **I am pretty new to react.**
My API call is working fine.

in my MovieCard.js component I can access my Title, Release etc.

```
  render() {
    const {
      Title,
      Released,
      Genre,
      Plot,
      Year,
      Poster,
      imdbRating
    } = this.state.movieData;

    return <Formular />;
  }
}
```

Now I have another component called Formular. How can I access my data from MovieCard to Formular?
I am thankful for any hints!

Thanks.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
    const {
      Title,
      Released,
      Genre,
      Plot,
      Year,
      Poster,
      imdbRating
    } = this.state.movieData;

    return <Formular Title={Title} Released={Released} ... />;
    // or <Formular {...this.state.movieData} />
    // but this implies you want to use everything and will always be the case no matter what new props you add
  }
}
```